# Compiling QT 5.0

Tags: qt, qt5

I want to compile QT 5.0 similar to the package that is offer on http://qt-project.org/downloads for Visual Studio 2012.

I followed these instructions http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building-Qt-5-from-Git and they work pretty well, only problem is, if I rename the folder where I compiled QT (or move the folder someplace else), Visual Studio starts complaining when I try to build a QT Application, that it does not find debug information or platform is missing, is like somehow the compilation files embedded the full path inside them to look for dependencies instead of been relative paths.

The reasons I do not use the package provided for VS in the website is because I also need an x86 version of it.

Another problem I am facing is that the compilation folder has thousands of files that takes a long time to move or delete, in the package from the website there are not so many files.

Does anyone know what options I have to give QT when compiling it the first time?

I use “-debug_and_release -c++11 -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests”

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you renaming or moving the compiled Qt? I never ever have had to do that on windows and I have used Qt for 5+ years.

Comment: Plain and simple: you can't move Qt after you configure it. You need to get the right paths from the start.

Comment: What I want to do also, is to compile QT in 1 computer and distribute the compilation folder to my team, that way they do not have to compile QT themselves

Answer (score 0):

On VS there should be Qt5 menu. There must be something like Qt Options. From the Versions tab you must add the new path as a new version and probably remove the old path because it does not exist anymore. Probably you will also need to change the project's Qt version from the project's context menu. I don't have VS in front of me but according to my visual memory this should do the trick.

Comment: Hi, it compiles ok, but when I try to execute the program from VS it tells me that is fails to load the platform windows.